# Should we have a "surface travel" tag as well as an "overland" tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

The way I had always thought about the term "overland" in relation to travel was that it included all forms of travel other than air travel despite one literal interpretation that "land" could mean "dry land".

Am I the only one who thought of it this way or do most people think of it the literal way?

In fact the two currently existing Wikipedia articles, *[Overland travel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overland_travel)* and [*Overlanding*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlanding) make no mention of seas or oceans neither, to include nor to exclude water transport.

But dictionary definitions do specifically oppose "land" to "water" or "sea" in this term, though they don't necessarily go into travel-specific senses or usage.

So at the moment there are quite a few questions tagged [overland](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overland) which include travel over the sea but not in the air.

So there are a couple of interrelated points:

- "Overland" never includes sea travel **vs** "overland" includes sea travel to some people
- Even if it turns out that to most people "overland" does not include sea travel for most people, is it beneficial to the site to separate them into two tags or not?
- I think the best term for the other tag if we did decide to split should be *[surface-travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/surface-travel)* since I've hear it used but thought it was just a more pedantic or long-winded way to say"overland".
- If we decide to keep the questions together under one tag even if the meanings are not the same, should we retain [overland](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overland) as its name and just update the tag wiki, or should we extended it to something like [overland-and-surface-travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overland-and-surface-travel)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep [overland](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overland), make [surface-travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/surface-travel) a synonym, untag all [overland](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overland) questions that involve *only* sea travel.

Answer (score 0):

What do we do with the [submarine](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=submarine) questions?

I would not invent an artificial term. We could go for [airtravel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airtravel), [landtravel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/landtravel), and [seatravel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seatravel).

In case a question fits both sea travel and overland we could just use both tags.

Comment: Haha I did think of that briefly, being [tag:below-surface-travel] (-: Thankfully they already have their own tag.